# Change the downloads folder to downloads in other partition and mount at bootup

Tags: dual-boot, nautilus, downloads, partitioning, automount

I have a setup where I basically split my hard drive into three partitions (forgetting the swaps and allsorts)

1. Windows partition
2. Ubuntu
3. Data

I would like to get things set up in a manner in which I can use the data partition for Ubuntu and Windows automatically, so if I download something, it automatically ends up in the download folder placed in the data partition.

I've tried Ubuntu tweak end editing `users-dirs.dirs`, which both initially seem to work, but....

For some reason or another, the data partition doesn't mount on boot up despite the "mount on boot" option in the drive being set.

Therefore, nautilus can't reach the intended folders and things go wrong.

How can I make sure the data drive mounts at boot up as intended?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the contents of your `/etc/fstab` file. Also, please explain where you've set the "mount on boot" option. I guess you used some kind of GUI thing but it would be best to specify what and how.

Comment: I've been going at it myself in the mean while, and problem solved. 
i didn't edit fstab, but apparently mounting ntfs drives on boot is slightly different than other drives, so i looked up how to mount ntfs drives, made the changes in drive and that fixed the problem.

http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/howto-mount-ntfs-part-disk-in-ubuntu

ps: the GUI tool was specified, it's named 'Ubuntu tweak', but it's just as easy to use gedit.. anyway, that wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to follow these directions for creating a separate home partition, changing only minor details to suit your needs. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving